# How to make controls resizing with window stop when they reach the edge of a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm building a Windows Forma Application UI in Visual Studio 2017 in C#. I have a button ("Replace") and a label ("Search Results") that are inside a pane. I have panel anchored to "Top, Left, Right" and the two controls at "Top, Right". What I want the two controls to do is to move with the main window form if it's expanded or shrunken to a different size but stop once they hit the left wall of the panel. As I have it right now, the two controls hide within the panel and disappear if the window is shrinks to a small enough size. How can I get the controls to stop moving to the left once they reach the left wall of the panel??

[image]

Comment: The designer can't do that.  You would have to code it.

Comment: Set all borders of the panel to be anchored. Then set a minimum size for the Panel to be wide enough to show the whole body of the button and the label. Button and label should be anchored Top, Right

Comment: If i set all panel borders to be anchored, then they'll also move up and down. I just want them to move left and right but then stop when they reach that red line area which is the left end of the panel.

Comment: @LarsTech how would I code it? This is my first time ever using WFA and C# so i'm still learning as I go.

Comment: You must set the form's MinimumSize property, it doesn't get any simpler than that.  A TableLayoutPanel might be useful to do a better job of arranging the controls, but it runs out of gas too when the window just gets to small to still be useable.

Comment: @HansPassant The minimum size worked! I tried doing that before but for some reason It needed a min size of 350 to work. I thought that was too much. But thank you! I'll consider using the TableLayoutPanel for my upcoming controls. You can answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant, I was able to fix it by setting a minimum size to the control. You just click on the panel control, go to the properties and set a minimum size value. I had to go pretty high, so I thought (450,40), so keep trying different sizes until you can get the controls within that panel to not disappear under the panel or keep forever moving left when the window is shrinking to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the forms `OnResize`

```
//To center
MyControl.Location = new Point(Panel1.Width / 2 - MyControl.Width / 2, MyControl.Location.X);

//To left
MyControl.Location = new Point(0, MyControl.Location.X);

//To right
MyControl.Location = new Point(Panel1.Width - MyControl.Width, MyControl.Location.X);
```